# How to use nth-child with :hover to style multiple children?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

JS Fiddle for easier debugging: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GregsFiddle/WyC7Y/1/

I am trying to setup this css so when you mouseover nine, nine and below get their bg color changed.

Mouseover 5, and 5 and below have their color changed.  You get the idea.  I am not sure how to use the nth-child(-n+#) selector with :hover.

```
ol.motivationBox .motivationBars li:nth-child(10):hover:nth-child(-n+9) {
background-color: #008cba;
}
```

That bit of code is not functioning. What did I format incorrectly?

Comment: Since this only functions right to left, which is not my goal I think I may just use JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you *currently* can't transverse the DOM tree, this seems to be the only thing possible in pure CSS.

Basically, the general sibling combinator, `~`, allows us to access all **succeeding** sibling elements.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M8KtS/)

```
ol.motivationBox .motivationBars:hover ~ .motivationBars,
ol.motivationBox .motivationBars:hover {
    background-color: #008cba;
}
```

.. if you wanted to use jQuery and select **preceding** sibling elements, you could use this:

[**ALTERNATIVE EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T5ZKq/)

```
$('.motivationBox .motivationBars').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('active');
    },
    function(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
    }
);
```

Comment: That works completely! Anyway to make it function left to right? That would be ideal.

Comment: Could you give me a quick hand one more time?  I am not super familiar with Jquery.  Is there a way to add to that function, so that if a user clicks one of the list items that the class will remain set even after mouse focus is removed?   I like how it functions how, its perfect how I wanted, just need a click to keep the classes selected.

Comment: Yes! But is there a way to keep the hover function as well.  So it functions like your first example, unless an LI is clicked, and then it will keep the active classes despite being moused off?   (apologies if I am explaining this poorly)